# Create Partition Based on Customer Account

Tags: hadoop, hive, database-partitioning

I need to partition a big Hive Table based on customer identifier (account number like 12345678).

In particular, I am looking for a function that gets customer_id and then converts it into a numerical value like 0-9 so it becomes my partition. By doing so, I have 10% of my customers in each partition.

> for example, f('123455') returns 4

Appreciate hint

Comment: Hint: read about "hash partitioning". Used by distributed NoSQL like Cassandra (and optionally HBase) to, well, distribute the load and avoid Hot Spots. Also available in Oracle since ca. 20 years...

Comment: Blogs about HBase should be particularly useful because hashing is optional and DIY.

Comment: In Hive or Spark, you can define your own UDF to accomplish this

Comment: @cricket_007, thanks. maybe remainder of 10 can lead to a number between 0 and 9 to keep as partition?

Comment: Mod 10 will result in that range, yes